# Young adult book about siblings with powers and dragons

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dragons

I'm looking for the name of a young adult book I read maybe twenty years ago about a girl and her younger brother hiding out in a castle with a secretive owner.

Both siblings have some sort of power, I think the sister could speak with animals. They were forced into an army entirely composed of soldiers with powers that was going to fight a similar army from another country. They escaped or ran away and somehow ended up at the castle and I think the sister was hired to care for the owners son.

The castle has a locked area that they aren't allowed into but the owner goes there at night to feed dragons that he is hiding, which the sister discovers. They end up becoming romantically involved.

The only other detail I can remember is that the castle owner wears gloves to hide his power to be able to see someone's future by touching their skin.

Comment: Congrats on finding your book! I have marked your question as a duplicate, but please note that this is not a censure, and your question was a good and detailed one. We just do this for bookkeeping purposes to tie those questions together to make them easier to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this fellow searching on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/497405-solved-dragon-brother-and-sister-government-training-military-force-th), this may be *[The Secret of Dragonhome](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/764640.The_Secret_of_Dragonhome)* by John Peel.

[image: Front cover of The Secret of Dragonhome]

> Melayne and her young brother Sarrow are Talents, hunted by the King's relentless Seekers. If their Talent is discovered, they will be sent to their death. So they must hide...or die.
>
> Melayne and Sarrow find refuge at Dragonhome, the mysterious estate of the shadowy Lord Sander. Lord Sander also has something to hide--a dark and fantastical secret that haunts his every move. In order to save herself and her brother, Melayne must confront forces much stronger than her talent--tempests of magic, desire, and betrayal. If Melayne is not careful, her truth will be revealed.
>
> Melayne must unlock the secrets of Dragonhome. As danger approaches, it will be her only hope.

Found with a search for `site:goodreads.com brother sister castle dragons gloves psychometry`